# associative arrays limit in awk. memory usage

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file with more than 20 million records and want to sum 5th column for every unique value of 1st column, i have used the code below.

```
cat test.txt |awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{a[$1]+=$5;}END{for(i in a) print i"|"a[i];}'
```

maximum value of a[i] in the output is limited to 9999.

kindly help me...any solution??

Comment: awk does **not** stop counting at `9999`. There's something else about your problem that you haven't told us yet. What happens with a smaller file - do you get the results you expect then? Do you get all of the unique `$1` values output? Do you get any error messages or any other reason to think the issue is memory usage? Are you sure you have a `$1` for which the sum is greater than 9999?

Comment: when i ran this command on o/p of the above ,there are values greaterthan 9999 in$2  

cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}$2>9999'

however after using 
sort -t"|" -k2 file|tail 

 the values in the second column are only upto 9999...why so??

Comment: `sort` does alphabetical sort, not numeric. Try `sort -n ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat > file
1||||a|NOTICE A LETTER IN FIFTH
1||||5
2||||57
2||||34535
3||||34535353
3||||1
1||||1
$ cat file|awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{a[$1]+=$5;}END{for(i in a) print i"|"a[i];}'
1: 6
2: 34592
3: 34535354
```

What do you get with my data above?

Comment: 1|8
2|34592
3|34535354....this is working..i dont know y my file is not working..:(

Comment: Are you sure the sums aren't really 9999? `grep` some particural index (`$1`), upload to Pastebin and post the url?

Comment: is it because values of column 5 have both numerical values and strings??

Comment: Strings (e.g. `"17"`) have numerical value zero. The result of your math will be the sum of the numbers.